# chrome is blocking one of my intranet sites

Tags: google-chrome, security

for some reason chrome is blocking one of my intranet websites. If I open this site using another web browser, it is ok, but with chrome I get attached warning message. I know I can click on details and go to this unsafe site, but it is annoying when people use it to do their work. I could turn it off removing "Enable phishing and malware protection" under chrome setting, but that is not the right solution to this problem.

Any help will be really appreciate it.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to put it in the trusted websites? http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-add-trusted-sites-in-google.html If it worked tell me to post it as an answer

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: @SomeFreeMason there is no code, I am not coding the website. It is posted on one of our servers but is giving of above security message when we try to open it using chrome.

Comment: @cojimarmiami it is impossible for us to tell you why Chrome is suggesting that your Intranet site is not trustworthy without seeing the code.  Obviously there's either some Javascript or a redirect which is happening which violates a Chrome rule.

Comment: @SomeFreeMason how can I get the code? from "more tools -> view source" or "more tools -> developer tools"

Comment: On the other hand, if you do not have access to the code, then you cannot "fix" the problem.  All you can do is either ignore or not go to the site.

Answer (score 0):

McAfee SiteAdvisor is also reporting a security issue for swsworkorder.com:

> Report link: [swsworkorder.com](http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/swsworkorder.com)
>
> Warning: This link might be dangerous. We tested it and found security
> risks. Beware.
>
> Website category: Malicious sites

Though the McAfee for Business site does not show any issues with the domain name nor [IP address associated with swsworkorder.com](http://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/ip/default.aspx?ip=208.109.239.150). I checked the reputation for swsworkorder.com at [some other reputation checking sites](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/Internet/domains/domain-reputation-check.php), but none reported an issue, either.

Is the site Internet accessible, so could actually be scanned for malware by site safety checking scanners?

Comment: I can access the website if I click on details and then visit this unsafe site, but the weird thing is that this only happens with chrome and not with any other browsers, below is the link. It is a website posted in one of the company servers http://swsvr4x:40524/default.aspx

Comment: @cojimarmiami, if it doesn't happen with Firefox, that is strange, since according to the [Firefox Browser Privacy Notice](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/#health-report): "About twice per hour, Firefox downloads Google's SafeBrowsing lists to help block access to sites and downloads that are malicious or forged", so I'd expect the Firefox browser to provide the same result as the Chrome browser, unless Firefox has been [configured not to perform site security checks](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/firefox/site-check/) or an exception has been added for the site

Comment: @cojimarmiami, so the complaint from Chrome is not regarding the company's server, but, instead, about a link to swsworkorder.com which the browser sees included on a page on your company's server? I.e., swsworkorder.com is not a domain name used by your company? Or did you mean "hosted" rather than "posted" on one of your company's servers, so that the swsworkorder.com website resides on your company's server?